# Intellij start-up task lauch server as debug

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I'm setting up a configuration for win time with intelij (some seconds :D)

I want to launch my tomee server when i start intelij.
Intelij provide startup task, is exactly what i want but this launch as run.
And i always launch my server in debug mode to work.

It is possible to made a startup task but specify the debug mode ?
thanks you for reading, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203872